# How to implement ASP Identity IPasswordStore if I don't have hashed password stored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I have a MVC5 project with ASP Identity, I don't have direct access to user database instead I was provided with web services, for example:

```
bool register (string username, string password, string email) //password is plain text
bool login (string username, string password)
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to implement IUserPasswordStore because ASP Identity force me to use Hash while I'm not allowed to store hashed password because this web services will be used not just by me.

My UserStore.cs:

```
    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user)
    {
        //I'm suppose to provide hashed password here, but since I don't have any hashed password stored, I have no idea how to implement this method
        string passwordHash = userTable.GetPassword(user.Id);

        return Task.FromResult<string>(passwordHash);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(TUser user)
    {
        var hasPassword = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userTable.GetPassword(user.Id));

        return Task.FromResult<bool>(Boolean.Parse(hasPassword.ToString()));
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        //do nothing since I don't need to hash the password

        return Task.FromResult<Object>(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your application doesn't have a password store, don't implement this.

Override the PasswordSignInAsync method in the SignInManager, and have it call your web service.